# Function passed as reference inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I am studying a bit Angular docs and there's an assignment I do not really get.

```
setTimeout(() => this.seconds = () => this.timerComponent.seconds, 0);
```

Does it set a reference of this.timerComponent.seconds to this.seconds? Given that both seconds and timerComponent.seconds are methods, is it equivalent to the following?

```
 setTimeout(() => { this.seconds = this.timerComponent.seconds }, 0);
```

Comment: No... 1st one assigns a function and second one assigns a value

Comment: The first one stores a function in `this.seconds` which will return the actual value of `this.timerComponent.seconds` when `this.seconds()` is called. The second stores the value of `this.timerComponent.seconds` at the time of execution in `this.seconds`.

Answer (score 3):

It's equivalent to

```
setTimeout(() => { return this.seconds = (() => { return this.timerComponent.seconds; }); }, 0);
```

It passes a function to `setTimeout` that, when called, assigns a function to `this.seconds` that, when called, returns the current value of `this.timerComponent.seconds`.